# How to bind c++ member function to python just using only c/python api?

Tags: python, c++

i use c/python api to bind my class to python.
I make new module and bind just class type successfully.
c/python api have PyMethodDef structure to bind function to python class.

```
PyMethodDef pyMethodDef = { "PyFunction", PYFunction, METH_KEYWORDS | 
METH_VARARGS  , "PyFunction" };

PyObject *pFunc = PyCFunction_New(&pyMethodDef, NULL);
PyObject *pMethod = PyInstanceMethod_New(pFunc);
int result = PyDict_SetItemString(pPyClassDict, pyMethodDef.ml_name, 
 pMethod);
```

But, there is a terrible rule that bind function must have PyObject* return type and it must get 2 PyObject* arguments.

```
PyObject* PYFunction(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    char *s = "Hello from C!";
    return Py_BuildValue("s", s);
}
```

So i can not bind my class and member function like this.

```
class Position
{
   int x;
   int y;
  public:
   Position() {x = 0; y = 0}
   ~Potition() { }+
   void SetZero()
   {
      x = 0, y = 0
   }
}
```

It is impossible to change all member function's signature like below.
Because actually i have many class to bind.

```
PyObject* method(PyObject*, PyObject*)
```

Well the boost python will be a solution but it is too big to use.
I only need python binder and it's too difficult to use.

Is there have any way to bind c++ member function(method) to python just only use pure c / python api?
(PyMethodDef structure's second member is PyCFunction type...)

Comment: "*So i can not bind my class and member function like this*" - Why not?

Comment: @melpomene Because the PyMethodDef structure's second member is PyCFunction type. So the signature of binded function must keep PyObject* method(PyObject*, PyObject*).

Comment: I still don't see the problem.

Comment: @melpomene For example, i want to bind Position class constructor and SetZero() method. How should i gonna do? it has no signature like PyObject* method(PyObject*, PyObject*).

Comment: Write a wrapper function that has the right signature and calls your method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. well... maybe now i must search about meta programming.. 
I want to make simple python c++ binder, so i need auto make wrapper function for all class member functions...

Answer (score 0):

To get a simple wrapper working quickly, whilst having to write very little glue then SWIG is your best bet.

Say you want to wrap `example.{h,cpp}`, typically all you need to write is:

```
/* File: example.i */
%module example

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}
%include example.h
```

- `%module example` tells SWIG to generate a module called "example"
- `#include "example.h"` makes your C++ function definitions available in `example.i`
- `%include example.h` tells SWIG to export every function and class definition it finds directly in `example.h`.

Then run:

```
swig -c++ -python example.i # generates example.py and example_wrap.cxx
g++ -c -fPIC example.cxx
g++ -c -fPIC example_wrap.cxx -I /usr/include/python3.5
g++ -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o _example.so
```

And you are done. (For reference, I am using python 3.5 and SWIG 3.0)

## Function Overloading

A common pitfall is if you have overloaded functions that SWIG cannot disambiguate (eg. they overload integral types [`foo(int)` vs `foo(short)`], floating point types, or pointers vs references [`Foo*` vs `Foo&`]). You can add an ignore or rename directive in `example.i` to help it know which functions to ignore or how to expose them.

For example, given:

```
/* File: example.h */

int add(int a, int b);
short add(short a, short b);
long long add(long long a, long long b);
double add(double a, double b);
```

You could add the following to your `example.i`:

```
%ignore add(short, short);
%rename("add_long_long") add(long long, long long);
```

And then you could use it like:

```
>>> import example
>>> example.add(1, 2)  # add(int, int)
3
>>> example.add(1.5, 2)  # add(double, double)
3.5
>>> example.add_long_long(1, 2)  # add(long, long)
3
>>> example.add_long_long(1 << 30, 1 << 30)  # add(long, long)
2147483648
>>> example.add(1 << 30, 1 << 30)  # add(int, int)
-2147483648
```

Comment: My question is just only use python/c api. But i'm very thanks for your ask. This ask will benefit for another people.